# Проблема с запуском Докер контейнера при запуске контейнера жалуется что не находит директорию

Tags: dockerfile

Докер образ создается все зависимости устанавливаются но при попытке запуска контейнера пишет что директория не найдена хотя она главная в ней лежит весь проект.Dockerfile лежит на одном уровне с этой директорий я уже весь мозг себе сломал пробовал импорты в проекте менять не помогает. Вот такой у меня Dockerfile:

```
FROM python:3.11.8-alpine

COPY . .

RUN python3 -m pip install -r requirements.txt

CMD ["python", "bot_obuv/main_run.py"]
```

вот директорию bot_obuv и не видит

Comment: [как задать хороший вопрос](//ru.stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask). начните с заголовка. «проблема с тем-то» — очень малоинформативный заголовок.